# Which is the best drawable resource to use for close button?

Tags: android

Simple enough: I just want to put a little button with an [x] [image: close button] in it in the upper-right corner of my dialog.

I tried:

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_close_normal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

but was informed by Eclipse that this drawable is not public.

```
error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'src' with value '@android:drawable/btn_close').
```

Is there a "best practices" way to implement this, or am I stuck doing it from scratch?

ETA: Here is what my dialog currently looks like. I want to change that square in the upper-right corner to the [x] glyph.

[image: dialog image]

Comment: What type of layout is this in? You need to position the button somehow depending on the container

Comment: It's a RelativeLayout. I've got that part working ok, I just don't know how to implement the button itself. Is there a standard way to take advantage of the Android built-in close button? Or do I just cut-n-paste the image into my own app and implement it from scratch?

Comment: I think I understand your question, I will post an answer

Comment: Sounds like the question is posed a little confusing. Should not it sound "Which is the best drawable resource to use for close button?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are marked as non-public, you can unzip the android.jar file and import them to your project. Here I have extracted from SDK-19, XHDPI versions for you:

These are in order - normal, pressed, selected:

[image: normal]
[image: pressed]
[image: selected]

and here is source for `btn_close.xml` which you can put in your /drawable folder and reference as `@drawable/btn_close`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_close_pressed" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_close_selected" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_close_normal" /> 
</selector>
```

If you wanted to go further you can extract the earlier SDK versions and place them in appropriate /drawable folders.

Comment: *Sigh*. That's what I was afraid I'd have to do. Thanks for doing the donkey work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not married to using exactly that icon, there is another one android provides. I used the built in button resource without having to unpack anything.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/dismiss"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
     android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
     android:layout_gravity="end" />
```

I've got this imageView in a FrameLayout and have it appear in the upper right corner of the container. Clearly on the backend, I'd wire up an OnClick listener to implement the action.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to copy the files to our application. I was told by some Google employees that you should not reference the resources, rather copy them to your application.

One of the reasons for this is that if you reference a whole bunch of icons for your application, you are not guaranteed that every one of these is updated at the same time when new versions of the SDK is released. You might end up with some up-to-date fancy icons and some old ones :)

Already discussed alot about this stuff:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2rvmKqG1TBM

Answer (score 0):

The `btn_close_normal` is actually one of the states of the btn_close drawable: see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_close.xml)

Try using `@android:drawable/btn_close`

Comment: Actually, that's what I tried first. I still get the message: `error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'src' with value '@android:drawable/btn_close').`